# why remove function not working ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can you please tell me why remove function not working.I am removing the code from menu option.
http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/136/

```
 $('#remove').click(function(){
     alert('dd') ;
        $("#b-a-1").remove();
     $('#tree').jstree(true).delete_node("#b-a-1");
    })
```

Comment: Your example removes `#b-a-1` in the jsfiddle example you posted...?

Comment: Not it it not removing

Comment: My and anwser fiddle work when user expand "b"

Comment: your example removes #b-a-1 in the jsfiddle, but the plugin recreates it when you expand b.

Comment: so how to solve that problem ..can we expand first than remove .

Comment: @Dave I think I need to expand first "b" than I need to remove

Comment: @Dave any update ,is it possible to solve that problem

Comment: will let you know,, referring documentation

Comment: ok thanks if you get solution please post your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a slight mistake! Api isn't very clear, but the correct sintax is:

```
$("#tree").jstree(true).delete_node('b-a-1')
```

Instead of:

```
$("#tree").jstree(true).delete_node('#b-a-1')
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

<s>You need to escape special character `-` using double backslashes `\\`. From the **[docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**:</s>

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \\

```
$("#b\\-a\\-1").remove();
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/137/)**

---

You don't need to specify the `#` when delete the node when using `delete_node` method since it'll always treat your `obj` as a unique element:

```
$("#tree").jstree(true).delete_node('b-a-1') ;
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/142/)**

Comment: Seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Olease follow this steps .Run the fiddle .click remove and expand "b" element still there

Comment: we need to expand the "node" before delete

Comment: I goofed up. The minus sign is not a meta character. I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) ?

```
   $('#remove').click(function(){
        alert('dd') ;
        $("#b-a-1").empty();
        $('#tree').jstree(true).delete_node("#b-a-1");
    })
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/140/)

That does exactly what you need it to, removing it from the dom, even when you close and open the node again.

***Note:*** Only downfall i can see at the moment is that the you have to drop the menu down before clicking remove, else it doesn't remove the element..

Answer (score 0):

Just get the element in a variable and remove.

```
var a = $("#b-a-1");
    $(a).remove();
```

Comment: Why would you need another $() around a? Could as well do `$($(...)).remove();` .. .. Does not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Below code removes selected element. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/149/)

```
    var sel = $("#tree").jstree("get_selected"); 
    $("#tree").jstree("remove", sel);      
    $('#tree').jstree(true).delete_node(sel);
```